# How to use user's input in multiple targets in PHING?

Tags: phing

I have all my building tasks split into several targets which are not intended to be executed separately. I'm trying to use user inputted value from `targetA` in two other targets but they seem to be in a diffrent scope. One way of fixing that is to add `targetA` to the `depends` property of `targetB` and `targetC` but it results in `targetA` being called twice.

So is there any way to save that value globally? Or maybe ensure that target gets executed only once?

```
<target name="targetA" description="..." hidden="true">
    <input propertyName="property" defaultValue="default" ></input>
    <!-- some action goes on here -->
</target>

<target name="targetB" description="..." hidden="true">
    <echo message="${property}" />
    <!-- some action goes on here -->
</target>

<target name="targetC" description="..." hidden="true">
    <echo message="${property}" />
    <!-- some action goes on here -->
</target>

<target name="install">
    <phingcall target="targetA" />
    <phingcall target="targetB" />
    <phingcall target="targetC" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, found the solution.
Property scopes seem to be nested one into another, so we can describe `input` target, put all our inputs there and then define main target `install` as depending on `input`. Now we will have all of our properties available for all the targets invoked from `install`  like that:

```
<target name="input" description="..." hidden="true">
    <input propertyName="property" defaultValue="default" ></input>
    <!-- more inputs here -->
</target>

<target name="targetB" description="..." hidden="true">
    <echo message="${property}" />
    <!-- some action goes on here -->
</target>

<target name="targetC" description="..." hidden="true">
    <echo message="${property}" />
    <!-- some action goes on here -->
</target>

<target name="install" depends="input">
    <phingcall target="targetB" />
    <phingcall target="targetC" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this a lot.  Another approach is to save and retrieve properties from a file.  This permits more flexible dependencies among tasks, and has the added benefit of saving values between sessions.

For example, make each input target begin with:

```
<propertyprompt propertyName="site_dir" promptText="Name of site directory" promptCharacter="?" useExistingValue="true" />
<if>
  <available file="${site_dir}/build.props" />
  <then>
    <echo msg="Retrieving stored settings from ${site_dir}/build.props" />
    <property file="${site_dir}/build.props" />
  </then>
</if>
```

Grab any inputs you want, with useExistingValue="true" if you want to skip the question if you already have answer.  Then end the target with:

```
<echo msg="Updating stored settings in ${site_dir}/build.props" />
<exportproperties targetfile="${site_dir}/build.props" />
```